# tensorflow on 32 bit SDK in java on windows

Tags: java, tensorflow, build, 32-bit

I have a Java program with needs a 32 bit SDK to run. I want to integrate tensorflow to the program for loading an object detection model and feed images to it. My question is:

1. How can I obtain the tensorflow_jni.dll that works with 32 bit SDK? I am aware that it can be 'built from source'. What does this mean and how do I get about doing this on a windows machine. The machine itself is 64 bit
2. If 1 is not possible then, is there an alternative to tensorlfow I can use in java (32 bit).